# Have two mouse events, one right after the other, and have both be saved as different variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, mouseevent, mouse

So I am currently using pygame to print a rectangle to the screen. Wherever the user clicks, I want the rectangle to move there instantly. I got that working, but now I want the user to be able to change the shape and size of the rectangle every time it moves. I have all of that set up, I am just having problems with the mouse event.

So I basically want to click once, have that coordinate be stored as a variable, click again, and have the new click be stored as a variable.

My code currently right now will pass in coordinates the coordinates of where I clicked in for the top left hand corner, but at the same time it puts those coordinates in for the bottom right hand corner, so basically a tiny dot appears.

```
import pygame

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, corner1, corner2, color):
        self.corner1 = corner1
        self.corner2 = corner2
        self.color = color

    def setCorner1(self, newCorner1):
        self.corner1 = newCorner1

    def setCorner2(self, newCorner2):
        self.corner2 = newCorner2

    def paint(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (self.corner1[0], self.corner1[1], int(self.corner1[0] - self.corner2[0]), int(self.corner1[1] - self.corner2[1])), 0)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    size = width, height = 800,700
    backgroundColor = [0, 0, 255]
    #c = Circle([400,300],40,[255,128,128] )
    r = Rectangle([400,300],[500,400],[255,128,128] )

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                r.setCorner1(event.pos)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                r.setCorner2(event.pos)

        # Handle Drawing:
        screen.fill(backgroundColor)
        r.paint(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now every time you click it sets both corner1 and corner2 to the same value. The code runs over the first `if` statement, sees it's true and executes it. Then it moves to the second if statement (independent of the first), sees that one is also true and executes that one.

I'm assuming that you want to store the first click as corner1 then a subsequent click as corner2? In order to do this you'll need to have something that differentiates the two. I added a variable named `switch`

```
switch = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        return
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if switch == 0:
            r.setCorner1(event.pos)
            switch = 1
        else:
            r.setCorner2(event.pos)
            switch = 0
```